# using PHP locally on low performance machine

Tags: php, sql, localhost

I would like to make a website using PHP and SQL (Preferably PHPmyAdmin/mariaDB) for the laptop of my dad. Something like a custom homepage. But his laptop isn't very impressive (9 years old i believe).

I'm using XAMPP for all my projects (School & Personal) but my father don't need all the tools that XAMPP has. When my father boots up his laptop and opens his browser the page has to be there and should be able to use the database thats all that needs to happen.

Code editing and testing will be done on my own computer with XAMPP.
We wont use a server. Everything will be run on localhos.

Would XAMPP be a good program to use on my father's laptop or is there a better alternative?

Comment: fyi: PHPmyAdmin and MariaDB are different things.

Comment: "good" is relative here, as so often. Good in terms of not much to do for the installation and least effort for you to program the application, maybe. A better way in terms of performance maybe is a handmade installation and configuration of the various components like the web server, the database server, etc.. A maybe even better approach is not to write something, that isn't meant to be a web application, as a web application but as a desktop application instead. Throws the webserver overhead overboard.

Comment: If i understand correctly you want to create a custom homepage for your dad so he can browser pages he likes the most and only these? Why do you exactly need xampp stack for him? Is he going to learn programming? To be honest i am a bit confused on what you are trying to achieve, what needs you and your dad have.

Comment: @stickybit thanks for the feedback. You and parhu_panter gave me the ansers i was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a virtual host and set that virtual host as homepage on your father's laptop browser.

Yes you can use other alternatives but Xampp is an good choice. you can hide the Xampp service and it keeps running in background so you don't need to give it a start every time.

In this way by default the virtual host will be opened and your father will be able to view your website every time. Localhost is also fine but it gives a dev feeling so its better if you go for virtual domain, likewise it would feel more reliable.

Comment: So in short: XAMPP with autorun and starting apache and SQL autostart is your advise? if that is the case then i will use Xampp.

Comment: ya. Glad you found it useful. Accept the answer to let future readers know that this helped. @Sietse99